# How long does plumber's putty need to set before I mount a disposal unit?

Tags: plumbing, repair, sink

I'm about to replace a garbage disposal, and will replace the sink flange as well.  This will obviously entail sealing the new flange with plumber's putty.

My question is do I need to wait for the putty to cure before I start hanging the new disposal from the underside of the flange?  Or can I just insert the flange and immediately start installing the disposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plumbers putty does not need to cure. Use a generous amount on the flange and then tighten the flange bolts. The excess putty will be squeezed out and you can remove it. You can install the disposal right after installing the flange.

Comment: At least older putty contained linseed oil and hardened very ,very slowly. As answered, hardening is not the objective.

Answer (score 4):

Hang it immediately. Place a generous amount around the circumference under the flange and tighten it down as directed. The weight of the disposal plus the installed flange will compress the fresh putty so it will fill any voids under the flange. You can then peel off any excess in the sink around the flange.

Comment: I find that just the *weight* of the disposal is insufficient; it actually needs to be screwed down (up?).

Comment: @Huesmann - of course! Implied but not stated.

Answer (score 4):

The plumber putty is not made to cure. It takes 10-20 years for it to dry up and need to replace it.

Since it does not dissolve in water, you can use it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

What's probably confusing you here is the trend for sink flanges to tell you explicitly **not** to use plumber's putty and to use a silicone caulk instead. Those might not need cure time either (unless you're using a latex base, which I would strongly recommend you not use for that purpose).

Plumber's putty does dry out over time, but when you pull it out of the tub it comes in, you'll quickly realize why it doesn't dry out easily: it's pretty oily. It has to be, to resist the water at the bottom of your sink. While it will dry out, it will still be there to physically seal the narrow gap between the flange and the sink. The only time you'll have to mess with it is if you remove the flange (i.e. replacing a garbage disposal). Regardless of the state of the putty, I would scrape any old putty off (it becomes brittle when dry) and apply new putty.

Because the seal is formed when you tighten the flange down, there's no waiting for the putty to set. use a wad of putty to pull as much excess out of the sink and you're ready to hang your disposal or plumb your strainer.

Comment: The reason often being that putty can stain white components or degrade plastic ones.